# Returning after a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, printing

I need to create my own `HashCode()` method which computes the HashCode of a `String`.

My code looks like this so far

```
    public long HashCode(String n){
        long x = 0;
        for(int i=0; i >= n.length()-1; i++){
            x =+ 31^(n.length() -1) * n.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Long.toString(x));
        return x;
    }
```

My println prints `"0"` although it has been altered inside the for loop.
Is there any way to return the changed `x`, rather than the initialized `x=0`?

Comment: What String you are passing to this function?

Comment: "Cat" which should return 67510.

Comment: I wonder whether its `i>=n.length-1` or `i<=n.lenth-1`

Comment: Sidenote: do you mean `x += ....` instead of `x =+`?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I made a lot of dumb mistakes. Sorry! Newbie java coder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = 0;  and i >= n.length()-1;
```

then for loop is never executed.

Instead use

```
for(int i=0; i < n.length(); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition should be  `<=` not `>=`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n.length() - 1; i++) {
        x = +31 ^ (n.length() - 1) * n.charAt(i);
    }
```

More over

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
            x = +31 ^ (n.length() - 1) * n.charAt(i);
        }
```

Is enough.

And as per you comment , *"Cat" which should return 67510*, Your logic needs to be change.

[Check here](https://ideone.com/xHKBzh), For "Cat" as a input, Your code producing `247`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other corrections, it looks like you meant to use the `+=` but instead your code says `= +`

```
x =+ 31^(n.length() -1) * n.charAt(i);
```

should be

```
x += 31^(n.length() -1) * n.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
for(int i=0; i <= n.length()-1; i++){  
      //OR
for(int i=0; i < n.length(); i++){
```

Instead of

```
for(int i=0; i >= n.length()-1; i++){
```

?

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
        long x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n.length() - 1; i++) {
        x += 31 ^ (n.length() - 1) * n.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(Long.toString(x));
```

your condition was wrong , try debuging your code to find out what the problem is